# How to get a value from map in a map?

Tags: javascript

I have a map where there are three values for every key, and can print them. However, I don't know how to reference each individual value.

```
const planinfo = await statement.planInformation(pool);
//  console.log(planinfo);
  let planinfoMap = new Map()
  planinfo.forEach(value=> {
    planinfoMap.set(value.plansubdomain, new Map([
      ['plancode',value.plancode],
      ['urlbucket',value.urlbucket],
      ['planemail',value.planemail]
      ]))
  })
// get subdomain here
console.log(planinfoMap.get(subdomain));

Map(3) {
  'plancode' => '222',
  'urlbucket' => 'somes3bcuket',
  'planemail' => 'mailme@somewhere.com'
}

Map(3) {
  'plancode' => '111',
  'urlbucket' => 'thiss3bucket',
  'planemail' => 'someemail@email.com'
}
```

How do I reference plancode, urlbucket, and planemail individually?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the object's properties. For an exhaustive explanation read the [doc on Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) and the [doc on Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```
let oneMapObject = planinfoMap.get(subdomain);
console.log("You mapped: %s, %s, %s", oneMapObject.get("plancode"), oneMapObject.get("urlbucket"), oneMapObject.get("planemail"));
console.log("This mapObject has plancode: %s", oneMapObject.plancode);
console.log("Another way to look at it: %s & %s (urlbucket and planemail)", oneMapObject["urlbucket"], oneMapObject["planemail"] );
```